# Is there a way to not track contributions made to a particular repository on Github?

Tags: git, github

I maintain a Github repo where I commit notes and supporting information for other github repos. I don't want to count the commits I make to this repo as this is not real code. Is it possible to do that on Github?

Comment: Have you tried [private](https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/setting-repository-visibility#making-a-repository-private) repositories ? You can change the visibility of contributions on private repositories, have a look [here](https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/publicizing-or-hiding-your-private-contributions-on-your-profile)

Comment: I am aware of them. I wondering if it's possible to have the repo public and not track the contributions.

Comment: I guess it's not possible because it probably defeats the purpose of a repository being public

Comment: Confirmed by __GitHub__ [support](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/142#issuecomment-561364258) in this issue [page](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/142)

Comment: Thanks for that information.